# Server control in server control ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I'm trying to learn how to make server controls for asp.net. I use DevExpress which are 3rd party server controls. I'm trying to add a DevExpress button to my server control.

```
public class Class1 : CompositeControl
{
    private DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton btnTest;

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {            
        btnTest.RenderControl(writer);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        btnTest = new DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton();
        btnTest.Text = "wazzzup"; 
        Controls.Add(btnTest);
    }
}
```

For some reason the button will not show up in the design view unless there is another devexpress control on the same page as my server control. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try adding `base.Render(writer);` after `btnTest.RenderControl(writer);`.

Comment: You only need to register a control using [@Register] if using in the markup, but not in custom controls.  It should work within the control... try doing @Ingenu's suggestion and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: Actually I was wrong, it will register the devexpress control using btnTest.RenderControl(writer); The only problem is it wont show up in the design view unless there is another devexpress control on the same page. (I modified my question)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inheriting from CompositeControl, you shouldn't override Render.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea.aspx
Microsoft is doing it in this example, do you need to override the Render() function in order to output the controls?

Comment: @rickster: No, the normal behaviour with CompositeControls is that it will by default render whatever control tree you build inside the CreateChildControls method. (I don't see any good reason for the MSDN sample you pointed at to complicate things by overriding render, as what they do could also be done in CreateChildControls. Especially since they don't bother to explain why they did it that way...)